# Getting "Type 'Float' does not conform to protocol 'ForwardIndex'" Error with Ranges in Xcode Beta 4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I updated to Xcode Beta 4, I started getting a weird error in my projects when I create ranges (like `Range<Float>`). It says `Type 'Float' does not conform to protocol 'ForwardIndex'`. If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, that'd be great.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

It's not dependent on my project. I opened up a blank playground and I got the same error.[image]

Comment: This depends on where you're trying to use the range, not the range itself. Show more code.

Comment: @jtbandes - What exactly are you looking for? Like wether it's in a protocol/structure/class, or what? I'll see if I can recreate it by itself.

Comment: @jtbandes - I updated the question with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `Float` does not conform to `ForwardIndex`. All the `UInt*` and `Int*` types do. Unfortunately it seems non-`ForwardIndex` types cannot currently be used in ranges. If you think this is wrong, [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

---

#### DANGER ZONE

You can eke out an implementation of `ForwardIndex` for `Float`, by implementing `successor()`:

```
extension Float : ForwardIndex {
    // a method of the private _Incrementable protocol
    public func successor() -> Float { return self + 1 }
}
let f = Range<Float>(start: 3, end: 4) // "Range(3.0,4.0)"
```

But this breaks as soon as you try to use it in certain ways:

```
switch x {
case f: // 'Range<Float>' is not convertible to '_OptionalNilComparisonType'
    println("f")
// ...
```

You might be able to get around this somehow, but it's probably not worth it. If you're trying to compare floats, rounding error is going to mess you up anyway!

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll just make my own structure, then.